# ios programming: Keeping user configuration in memory vs storage

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller, swift2

In a very basic app, I have 2 ViewControllers, lets call them ViewController and SettingsViewController.

A 'Settings' button on ViewController Segues the user to SettingsViewController

At SettingsViewController, user may set a timestamp using a UIDatePicker or not and hit 'Done' to Segue back to ViewController

Now when the user goes back to SettingsViewController again, Im trying to ensure that data from the previous visit to this VC is still relevant, instead I find the VC is new and has no recollection! Does this mean I have to store everything I need to remember before user leaves SettingsViewController?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep. Once you return back to ViewController from SettingsViewController, SettingsViewController will be destroyed and data in it lost.

Depending what you are saving you could save data simply using `NSUserDefaults`.

For example, to store a String:

```
let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
userDefaults.setValue("saveMe", forKey: "someKey")
```

Then to access this later in your other ViewController:

```
let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()    
userDefaults.stringForKey("someKey")!
```

Comment: Added a little example to save and then access a String. You can save many other data types using NSUserDefaults as well.

Comment: Thanks, but what if I wanted to retain objects in memory as opposed to storing them each time between segues, which seems a bit inefficient. Is there no way to retain the state of a view among transitions?

Comment: Not really. Views are destroyed to keep things efficient so that memory isn't wasted on a view that cant be seen by the user and also may not be returned to. To keep the data purely in memory you would have to pass the data from SettingsViewController back to ViewController... and then pass it forward from ViewController to SettingsViewController when going back the other way. `NSUserDefaults` is actually pretty fast, especially when reading and in fact values are cached in the short term so that it doesn't need to read from disk.

Comment: But, I would say that `NSUserDefaults` is designed to store small amounts of information, such as the date in your example. It can store things like arrays and dictionaries but I wouldn't store particularly large ones in it.

Comment: Thanks, sounds like a reasonable argument and I'll use this